# How to assign hotkeys to "fake buttons" in an interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I'm using Apex 5

I have an Interactive Report on page 1 of my application. The last column of this report contains links or "fake buttons" to page 2. Each row has a unique "fake button" so that each button can bring up a unique report on page 2. I'd like to assign keyboard shortcuts to the first ten or so buttons in the report to make navigation through the app faster.

The reason why this is not straightforward, is because the "fake button" is actually a value in a result row of the Interactive Report that happens to be a hyperlink. I can't seem to access each row's unique button because on an html level, the buttons are all the same. I've seen other people assign hotkeys to real buttons (i.e. Button items placed in regions separate to Interactive Reports), but not to rows of link columns within the Interactive Report.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker gave me a solution!

In the SQL query that creates the table you need to select rownum (you need to do this in a nested Select statement to keep the order of the table...). I wanted to limit the amount of hotkeys assigned to 9 so I added the following in the end of the (outer) select statement:

CASE 
     WHEN rownum < 10 THEN '' || rownum 
     ELSE '' 
END

I aliased the rownum column as Hotkey.
Then in the link "fake button" column, go to Link Attributes, and type in accesskey = #Hotkey#. The way the condition works, all the rows are being assigned an accesskey value, but after the first nine rows, that value is null.

I hope this saves someone some time!